# Is it necessary to use in the array NavLink, Interface?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

I'm new to react and typescript, I have a DupNavLink component that creates an array of NavLink. There is also an Interface `faceNavLink` which I use for the typing of the object in the map.

Do I need a `faceNavLink` interface? And if so, how should the structure of my interface be?

Here is my example on codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/x6l89n75o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to define all those values in your `faceNavLink` interface.
You can just extend the interface `NavLinkProps` provided by `react-router-dom` and extend it with your changes.

In your `Interface.tsx` you can do something like:

```
import { NavLinkProps } from 'react-router-dom';

export default interface faceNavLink extends NavLinkProps {
  readonly id: string;
}
```

In this case you'll have all the properties from `NavLink` plus your custom `id: string`.

Comment: if i understand you correctly i should have changed the faceNavLink interface to                                              
   export default  interface faceNavLink extends NavLinkProps {
  readonly id: string;
  readonly text?: string,
},If so, I get an Error.  
https://github.com/vzgo0022/NavLinkProps-/tree/master/src
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NOqd9Cw6HYY&feature=youtu.be

Comment: @EdgarYedigaryan, that is very weird, because here https://codesandbox.io/s/v81jvnzz55 I made your changes and it does not show any error. Does it shows the error when you run the app? If not, It might be some issue with vscode.

Comment: Yes shows. I fixed the error.What I did I first removed all My files and then downloaded from the github and install the modules.and it worked,Interestingly, Github showed that a new package  was added to package.json "i": "^ 0.3.6", https://cloud.mail.ru/public/HLt2/TVVDCbETd

Comment: Thanks for the answer my friend.